# Kohana 3.3 Database Config System

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm tried to set database config system.
I attach new database config, load group and try get field value:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database);
$config = Kohana::$config->load('site');
$value = $config->get('title');
echo Debug::vars($value);
```

But i get only an error:

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 16
>   bytes MODPATH\database\classes\Kohana\Config\Database\Reader.php [ 64 ]

Config table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `config` (
  `group_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `config_key` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `config_value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_name`,`config_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `config` (`group_name`, `config_key`, `config_value`) VALUES
('site', 'description', 'Description'),
('site', 'title', 'Test title');
```

Tell me please, what wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Config_Database` expects the config values to be [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). The error message is saying that the Reader was unable to `unserialize` the data you requested (because you seeded your database with non-serialized values). You should set the config values using:

```
$config->set('key', 'value')
```

For example:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database);
$config = Kohana::$config->load('site');       
$config->set('title', 'This is a title');
```

Now if we look at the data in the database you should see something like the following (take note of the format of the `config_value` field):

```
mysql> select * from config;
+------------+------------+-------------------------+
| group_name | config_key | config_value            |
+------------+------------+-------------------------+
| site       | title      | s:15:"This is a title"; |
+------------+------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```